# How to get all windows user accounts associated with a PC

Tags: c#, windows, active-directory, wmi

My work-pc user account is related to my work's active directory domain, but I also have 3 local Windows user accounts. I want to programmatically get usernames of these 4 accounts. I've tried using WMI and some powershell commands, but I either get only 3 local accounts or ALL domain accounts (me and all my coworkers). I can see what I need if go to User Accounts in control panel. Is there a way I can domain account only related to a particular machine.

Basically I want all these:

[image]

Comment: please use the build-in tool for attach the images, also do you have any code to post here?

Answer (score 2):

That list of profiles is kept in the registry at:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList
```

So you can read that registry key from your code. Those keys contain the SID of the accounts, which you can then translate into `DOMAIN\username` format, like this:

```cs
using (var profileList = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList")) {
    foreach (string keyName in profileList.GetSubKeyNames()) {
        using (var profile = profileList.OpenSubKey(keyName)) {
            if ((int) profile.GetValue("FullProfile", 0) != 1) continue;

            var sid = new SecurityIdentifier(keyName);
            Console.WriteLine(sid.Translate(typeof(NTAccount)));
        }
    }
}
```

Checking if the `FullProfile` value is `1` is just to exclude the `SYSTEM`, `LOCAL SERVICE` and `NETWORK SERVICE` accounts.